# Multiple calls to madvise

Tags: c++, linux

I'm reading the documentation for the [**madvise**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) system call on Linux.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to pass multiple "advice" values to `madvise`.  The `advice` parameter does not seem to take bit flags which can OR'd together, so it seems that `madvise` can only be called with one `advice` parameter at a time.

If I want to take advantage of multiple `advice` parameters, based on the use case of my application, is it acceptable to simply call `madvise` multiple times in a row?

For example, if I want to give the kernel a hint to start reading an mmap'd file in advance via `MADV_WILLNEED`, but I *also* know that my application will mainly use sequential reads, I can also take advantage of `MADV_SEQUENTIAL`.  I can't find any examples online that demonstrate how to pass multiple values to `madvise`, so I assume I just say:

```
int result = madvise(address, m_size, MADV_WILLNEED);
/* do error checking */

result = madvise(address, size, MADV_SEQUENTAL);
/* do error checking */
```

But I'm hesitant because I don't know if this "overwrites" the previous call somehow.  So is it possible to provide `madvise` with multiple `advice` parameters like this?

Comment: I asked a related question on https://github.com/jart/cosmopolitan/issues/765

Answer (score 5):

Every call will trigger one strategy for how the section of you mmap'ed data is handled -- and you cannot combine multiple strategies for the same section as they are conflicting in nature.

However you can apply different strategies to different parts of the file, which is why you have the address and size parameter.

Subsequent calls for the same section of the file will reset the previous strategy.

If your access is sequential, you should use MADV_SEQUENTAL -- it should do the read-ahead and then drop the pages once you have accessed them giving you optimal performance and memory management.

WILLNEED should be used for something where you don't want the OS to drop the pages once you have accessed -- you should use this or RANDOM if you have a Index block or something else where the access pattern is not easily determined.

Comment: _"Subsequent calls for the same section of the file will reset the previous strategy"_ -- this constradicts the [Linux source code](https://github.com/jart/cosmopolitan/issues/765#issuecomment-1462851028): E.g. `MADV_SEQUENTIAL` just sets some flags independent of some other `madvise()` flags.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to use `madvise` with multiple parameters. And yes, some of those `MADV_advices` are overwriting each other, say MADV_WILLNEED and MADV_DONTNEED. Quick check in `linux-mman.h` shows that advise constants are not bits, but a sequential constants (1,2,3,4,...) so it is not possible to combine them using `or`.

So multiple calls to madvise is the best choice, I believe